# shell: strange string concatenation behavior

Tags: bash, shell, string-concatenation

I write a scipt like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
  echo line ${line}
  pdbfile=${line}.pdb  
  echo pdbfile ${pdbfile}
done < myfile
```

The result is:

```
line pdb8mhtA
.pdbfile pdb8mhtA
```

While it is supposed to be

```
line pdb8mhtA
pdbfile pdb8mhtA.pdb
```

What's wrong with this? Why the string concatenation does not work? And why the strange dot at the beginning of the line?
I replace with `pdbfile=${line}'.pdb'`. That does not change the result.

Comment: Could there be carriage return (`\r`) characters in the input?

Comment: Can you try the following:  `od -xc myfile` and paste the result here?  The suspicion is that there is a strange character in the file which is messing things up.

Comment: I tested your script with simple copy/pasting, and it works fine. I tried adding a `\r` character after the 1st line of my input file (as suggested by @Biffen) and I get the output you've shown us. In order to strip Windows-style carriage return from your input data, I suggest running the following script : `sed -i 's/^M//g' myfile`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "string goes to the beginning of the line" is symptomatic of a carriage return in your `$line` that you can among many other ways remove with a `tr` pipe to your file:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
  echo "line ${line}"
  pdbfile=${line}.pdb  
  echo "pdbfile ${pdbfile}"
done < <(tr -d '\r' <file)
```

Comment: ...btw, re: edits, see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) describing why `IFS= read -r line` is more correct than `read line`, [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo) describing why arguments to `echo` need to be quoted, and http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html discussing the long history of chiding folks who use `cat` unnecessarily (doesn't really matter for `tr`, but if you get in the habit for using it, you might use it for `tail`, or `wc -c`, or another program where it means the difference between O(1) and O(n) operation).

Answer (score -2):

I've tried your script and it works fine for me:

```
./testConcat
line pdb8mhtA
pdbfile pdb8mhtA.pdb
```

btw you could try to "preserve" the "."

```
while read line
do
  echo line ${line}
  pdbfile=${line}\.pdb
  echo pdbfile ${pdbfile}
done < myfile
```

as you can see the result is the same

```
./testConcat
line pdb8mhtA
pdbfile pdb8mhtA.pdb
```

Comment: Thank you:) I've tried to escape the dot, but that did not help.